# На мобильном устройстве каунтер количества неактивен(не кликается) подскажите в чем проблема

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

```js
// Добавляем прослушку на всем окне
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  // Объявляем переменную для счетчика
  let counter;

  // Проверяем клик строго по кнопкам Плюс либо Минус
  if (event.target.dataset.action === 'plus' || event.target.dataset.action === 'minus') {
    // Находим обертку счетчика
    const counterWrapper = event.target.closest('.counter-wrapper');
    // Находим див с числом счетчика
    counter = counterWrapper.querySelector('[data-counter]');
  }

  // Проверяем является ли элемент по которому был совершен клик кнопкой Плюс
  if (event.target.dataset.action === 'plus') {
    counter.innerText = ++counter.innerText;
  }

  // Проверяем является ли элемент по которому был совершен клик кнопкой Минус
  if (event.target.dataset.action === 'minus') {

    // Проверяем чтобы счетчик был больше 1
    if (parseInt(counter.innerText) > 1) {
      // Изменяем текст в счетчике уменьшая его на 1
      counter.innerText = --counter.innerText;
    } else if (event.target.closest('.cart-wrapper') && parseInt(counter.innerText) === 1) {
      // Проверка на товар который находится в корзине
      console.log('IN CART!!!!');
      // Удаляем товар из корзины
      event.target.closest('.cart-item').remove();

      // Отображение статуса корзины Пустая / Полная
      toggleCartStatus();

      // Пересчет общей стоимости товаров в корзине
      calcCartPriceAndDelivery();
    }

  }

  // Проверяем клик на + или - внутри коризины
  if (event.target.hasAttribute('data-action') && event.target.closest('.cart-wrapper')) {
    // Пересчет общей стоимости товаров в корзине
    calcCartPriceAndDelivery();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="items counter-wrapper">
  <div class="items__control" data-action="minus">-</div>
  <div class="items__current" data-counter>1</div>
  <div class="items__control" data-action="plus">+</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы добавляете слушателя для события `click`:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {}
```

Это событие происходит только в том случае, если пользователь нажмёт кнопку мыши. На мобильных устройствах же мыши нет, соответственно событие там это не срабатывает. Если вы хотите отлавливать нажатие на экран на мобильных устройствах, то добавляйте слушателей для события `touchstart` или `touchend`

Более подробно о мобильных событиях:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: Inventor, не подскажешь куда именно засунуть слушателя событий touchend или touchstart , буду благодарен , если прикрепишь строчку кода